# Datos no se ingresan en hosting de produccion

Tags: php, hosting, cpanel

Estoy desarrollando un app con, Php 7.2, javascript, html5 y css3...  el app en el servidor local (LAMP) inserta el registro (crear un usuario) a la base de datos pero en el servidor que fue adquirido no ejecutando la misma consulta. Probé con un hosting de pruebas que poseo y ejecuta correctamente la consulta. Las especificaciones de mi server local:

```
     Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/7.2.5 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev 
     Perl/v5.16.3
     Versión del cliente de base de datos: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 
     20150407 - 
     $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
     extensión PHP: mysqliDocumentación curlDocumentación 
     mbstring Documentación
     Versión de PHP: 7.2.5
```

Las características del servidor de prueba que ejecuta correctamente la consulta:

```
cPanel Versión  70.0 (build 54)
Versión Apache  2.2.34
Versión PHP     5.4.45
Versión MySQL   5.6.39-83.1
```

Características del servidor que presenta el problema con el ingreso de los datos:

```
cPanel Versión  74.0 (build 1)
Versión Apache  2.4.34
Versión PHP 5.6.36
Versión MySQL   10.2.16-MariaDB
```

Para crear un usuario el sistema hace un directorio con el nombre de usuario y foto (con PHP), en el administrador de archivos del Cpanel se crea la carpeta, con el username y la foto dentro pero en la base de datos no se ingresa el registro.

la Clase con la que me conecto en el hosting esta con su db y user indicados.

```
class Conexion{

static public function conectar(){

    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pos",
                    "root",
                    "");

    $link->exec("set names utf8");

    return $link;

    }
}
```

La funcion que ingresa en el modelo el usuario:

```
static public function mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(nombre, usuario, password, perfil, foto) VALUES (:nombre, :usuario, :password, :perfil, :foto)");

    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datos["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $datos["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":perfil", $datos["perfil"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":foto", $datos["foto"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt->execute()){

        return "ok";    

    }else{

        return "error";

    }

    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = null;

}
```

Comment: Añade tu código, de otra manera no sabremos lo que está fallando

Comment: Cuando añadas el código podremos ayudarte a imprimir algún mensaje de error que te oriente sobre el fallo

Comment: O sea mas que todo quisiera saber si es posible que falle algo por la versión php o alguna otra forma ya que como detallo el código funciona en otros sitios solo en ese hosting no funciona y si existe alguna alternativa ? pero si es necesario subo el código aunque como detallo si funciona solo que creo que es la versión del servidor o algo en el hosting que no permite su funcionamiento

Comment: cual es el error que da?

Comment: @aloMalbarez No, el problema es que no lanza ningún error simplemente no ingresa los registros pero crea el directorio, quizá pueda ser un error con al versión de php ? o algo ? alguna recomendación ?

Comment: aparece algo activando el reporte `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ? existen las tablas que referencia `$tabla` ? si pones `127.0.0.1` en vez de `localhost` en el dbhost? dice algo `/var/log/apache2/error.log`? ó el errorlog del php.ini?

Comment: Pero en localhost no presenta algún error alguno ingresan los registros mi pregunta va mas por el lado si la versión de PHP o configuración del servidor hosting incurre en algo ? Puesto que el el app funciona correctamente en otros ambientes ..